# Which Hibernate ( or NHiberate) tags and/or mapping classes would I use to create mappings to the bridge table called contract?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, composite-key, bridge

Let's say I have a bridge table with more than two foreign keys that make up it's composite key.

For Example,

Goverment table
gov_id int primary key
cournty_name String

NonProfitOrg Table
nonProfit_id int primary key
NonProfit_name String

CommericalFirm Table
commercial_id int primary key
commerical_name String

( bridge table Called Contract )
Contract
gov_id
nonProfit_id
commercial_id

Which Hibernate ( or NHiberate) tags or mapping classes would I use to create mappings to the bridge table called contract?
Should I create a separate mapping class for the bridge table Called Contract?
Or Could we do this with the many-to-many tag in the Government mapping table and NonProfitOrg table and CommericalFirm Table?
Please tell me the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have functional data, other than just the foreign keys to the linked entities, in the contract table, then you need to map it as an entity.

You would thus have a OneToMany between Government and Contract, and another OneToMany between NonProfitOrg and Contract.

And since it's a regular entity, I strongly advise you to identify it with an autogenerated, single-column ID, just like the other entities.

Comment: Also, would I also have a OneToMany between CommericalFirm and Contract?

Comment: Yes, you would also have this association.

Comment: Does he really have functional data in Contract table? I don't see he mentioned any. He could use many-to-may between Government-NonProfitOrg and Government-CommercialFirm as well.

Comment: Yes, he does, since there is an additional commercial_id column, representing a Commercial.If he had two ManyToMany, he would have two join tables.